# Visual C++ Testing problem

Tags: visual-studio-2008, testing, visual-c++

I have installed VisualAssert and cFix. I have been using Visual Studio C++ and programming in CLI/C++. I have a working Chess Game Program that works perfectly by itself.....and I have been studying testing and have many examples(with tutorials) I have found on the net, that compile and run in Visual Studio.....

But as soon as I try and implement those tests on my chess game......I get this problem....

This is what its telling me

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ChessRound1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>stdafx.cpp
1>C:\Program Files\VisualAssert\include\cfixpe.h(137) : error C3641: 'CfixpCrtInitEmbedding' : invalid calling convention '__cdecl ' for function compiled with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>C:\Program Files\VisualAssert\include\cfixpe.h(235) : error C4394: 'CfixpCrtInitEmbeddingRegistration' : per-appdomain symbol should not be marked with __declspec(allocate)
1>C:\Program Files\VisualAssert\include\cfixpe.h(235) : error C2393: 'CfixpCrtInitEmbeddingRegistration' : per-appdomain symbol cannot be allocated in segment '.CRT$XCX'
1>C:\Program Files\VisualAssert\include\cfixpe.h(244) : error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'const CFIX_CRT_INIT_ROUTINE'
1>        Address of a function yields __clrcall calling convention in /clr:pure and /clr:safe; consider using __clrcall in target type
1>C:\Program Files\VisualAssert\include\cfixpe.h(137) : error C3641: 'CfixpCrtInitEmbedding' : invalid calling convention '__cdecl ' for function compiled with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\james\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\ChessRound1\ChessRound1\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>ChessRound1 - 4 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Im working with windows forms and have a heap of cpp source files.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you  James i want to  ask  same question.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set CLR switch to /clr (without pure and safe).

Comment: Thank you Alex, that is sort and it's all working for me. Big Help, thanks.